# error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am getting the following error when i try to assign the value to var.

> unsigned long var= 0x7137449123ef65cdULL;

Is unsigned long long supported in vc++6?

Error:-

Error 1  error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'

***Solution***

Based on the inputs from RogerRowland and Igor Tandetnik i resolved this issue.
Solution:

> "unsigned __int64 var= 0x7137449123ef65cdi64;

Comment: Did you miss off the `;` in your code too?

Comment: sorry.I forgot to add ; . vc++6 is very old.not sure the possibility of support for unsigned long long. :(

Comment: Yes, you may need to try `unsigned __int64` instead.

Comment: @RogerRowland ...and also `i64` suffix in place of `ULL`.

Comment: I changed the code . Now it works fine. "unsigned __int64 var= 0x7137449123ef65cdi64;"